# Відповідник до слова "скетч"

Tags: вибір-слова, відповідник

Цікавить чи є відповідник до слова "[скетч](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%87)", яке вживається у значенні "невелика комічна п'єса з двома, рідше трьома персонажами. Бере початок від народної інтермедії. Скетч отримав найбільше поширення на естраді".

На [Словотворі](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/sketch) є відповідники такі як "нарис" та "начерк", однак там слово "скетч" має значення "чорнове зображення якогось об'єкту, зроблене нашвидкуруч".

Отож, як бути зі словом "скетч" у значенні "невелика комічна п'єса" і як бути із таким словом як "скетч-шоу" (які стають все більш популярними, приклад українського скетч-шоу - "[Файна Юкрайна](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%AE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0)").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Якщо говорити про літературу, то найближча, мабуть, *[гумореска](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0)*:

> невеликий віршований, прозовий чи драматичний твір з комічним сюжетом, відмінний від сатиричного твору легкою, жартівливою тональністю

Якщо йдеться про її інсценізацію, то це *гумористична [сценка](http://sum.in.ua/s/scenka)*:

> Невеликий закінчений драматичний твір

Answer (score 5):

Як на мене, *нарис* цїлком підходить:

[Вікіпедія](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81)

> **На́рис** — невеликий твір, художньо-публіцистичного жанру, у якому зображено дійсні факти, події в житті конкретних людей. Найчастіше нариси присвячуються відтворенню сучасних подій чи зображенню людей, яких особисто знав письменник.
>
> **На́рис** — центральний жанр публіцистики, що передбачає оперативний відгук на суспільно важливу подію, розкриття образу цікавої особи, створення портрету колективу, розповідь про побут, звичаї й людей певного регіону своєї й чужої країни. Цей жанр дав назву одній з рольових спеціалізацій у журналістиці: автори нарисів тут називаються «нарисовці».

[СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/narys)

> 2. Оповідний художньо-публіцистичний твір, у якому автор зображує підмічені ним у житті дійсні факти, події, конкретних людей.